# Округление сотых после запятой в Java

Tags: java, double, round

Есть пара примеров :

```
  double a = 100.00;
  double b = 99.33;

  double res = b-a;   //Получится -0.67  OK

  double x = 100.00;
  double y = 99.95;
  double res2 = y-x;  // Получится -0.04 ???
```

Вопрос, почему во втором примере теряется 0.01 ? Как это можно исправить.
   Пробовал BigDecimal(ROUND_CEILING/FLOOR), но в таком случае уже первый вариант считается неверно.

**Отбрасывать знаки после запятой НЕ НУЖНО**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Получится -0.04" - только если Вы отбросите все, начиная с третьей цифры после запятой.

```
System.out.println(res2); // -0.04999999999999716
System.out.println(Math.round(res2 * 100) / 100.0); // -0.05
System.out.println(String.format("%f", res2)); // -0.050000
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", res2)); // -0.05
```

Answer (score 4):

Примитивы с плавающей точкой не гарантируют математическую точность в вычислениях из-за особенностей их представления в памяти и операций над ними (кстати, поэтому не следует проверять такие значения на точное равенство, а нужно проверять попадание в интервал) . Если нужна математическая точность, следует пользоваться объектами класса BigDecimal.